# How to determine a dependency graph solution is correct

Tags: unit-testing, testing, graph, dependencies

I created a class that takes a directed graph, a vertex in that graph, and outputs an acceptable sequence of vertices to lead to that vertex.

e.g.

- A->B
- A->C
- B->D
- C->D

The two possible sequences for vertex D are:

- A->B->C->D
- A->C->B->D

Now, I need to design a test to determine if a solution my program gives is correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an algorithm based on [Cyclomatic Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) to calculate the number of paths that should be found, which would be a good sanity check - esp if you have a very big graph, getting exactly the right number of paths would be reassuring (though not obviously a guarantee that the paths themselves are correct!). It is broadly speaking the number of edges minus the number of nodes - you'll see the nuances on that wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite common. There are essentially two similar and easy ways to deal with it:

- put the sequences of nodes in a set and check the set size and whether it contains all the sequences
- sort the sequences according to some known algorithm (e.g. by comparing one node after another). Now the order is always the same.

In Java this would mean:

- implement `equals` and `hashCode` for the sequence of nodes (if this is something like `List<Node>`, implement `equals` and `hashCode` for `Node` instead) and put them in `HashSet`. Then simply check if the set has correct size and contains both paths.
- make the sequence of nodes `Comparable` and sort them. Then the order is always known and fixed. In your case simply compare corresponding nodes one after another.

Comment: This seems to be assuming I know the solution beforehand.  I need to be able to put an extremely complex graph in, and have the solution checked specifically via the test.  Any ideas for that?